# Loop each cell from sheet1 and always replace in 1 cell at sheet2

Tags: excel, url, vba

I had a problem, when I want to use each name from C1 to C21 from sheet1 and insert in nameuser as url address. It suddenly delete each name from Sheet1 from C1 to C21 but it is not replace the destination B2 at sheet2 for every name.

```
Sub URL_Get_Query()

Dim wb As Workbook
Dim src As Worksheet
Dim tgt As Worksheet

Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Set src = wb.Sheets("Sheet1")
Set tgt = wb.Sheets("Sheet2")

Dim url As String
Dim symbol As String

tgt.Columns("B:C").Select
Selection.ClearContents
src.Select

Dim c As Range
Dim Rng As Range
Set Rng = Range("c3:c21")
For Each c In Rng
MsgBox (c.Address)

Rng = namerange

nameuser = namerange
'nameuser = src.Range("C3")
url1 = "URL;http://my001vs0253:81/user.aspx?username="
url = url1 & nameuser & "&userdomain=TP"

'"URL;http://my001vs0253:81/user.aspx?username=afiqg&userdomain=TP",

nameuser1 = "user.aspx?username="
nameurl = nameuser1 & nameuser & "&userdomain=TP_7"
'nameurl = nameuser1 & rRng & "&userdomain=TP_7"

With tgt.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
    url, Destination:=tgt.Range("B2"))


    '.CommandType = 0
    .Name = nameurl
    .FieldNames = True
    .RowNumbers = False
    .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
    .PreserveFormatting = True
    .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
    .BackgroundQuery = True
    .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
    .SavePassword = False
    .SaveData = True
    .AdjustColumnWidth = True
    .RefreshPeriod = 0
    .WebSelectionType = xlSpecifiedTables
    .WebFormatting = xlWebFormattingNone
    .WebTables = "22"
    .WebPreFormattedTextToColumns = True
    .WebConsecutiveDelimitersAsOne = True
    .WebSingleBlockTextImport = False
    .WebDisableDateRecognition = False
    .WebDisableRedirections = False
    .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
End With

Next
End Sub
```

Hope you may get my opinion. Thanks is advance.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  It always helps to post a bit of data,  A few rows of the values from sheet1 ColumnC and a few rows of the desired output (the result the code should produce) from sheet2 columnB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you can first read the data in the src worksheet into an array, and then use that array to build the data in your tgt worksheet. This will remove the direct link between the two worksheets, and possibly also the issue. Question is however why do you need to delete those columns? Deleting columns can provide issues like the one you are having now, so I generally try to avoid doing so.